# Resign an update for an APK published on playstore

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I'm writing an app and building an apk with an external program, not android studio.
ANd i'm using the javatool (into the jdk) to create the key store. But i have a question. How can i update and resign the apk and the keystore when i want to reelease an updated version?
Thank you

Comment: The JDK tools are outdated for signing Android apks. Use  `apksigner` from Android SDK to sign an APK file.

Comment: @Robert yes apksigner to sign an apk with a keystore, but i need to create a keystore first, and keystore for update, it's what i'm asking how does it work

Comment: If you want to update an existing app in PlayStore you have to use the same keystore as used for signing the app that is already in play store. Hence you don't have to create a new one.

Comment: ok thank, so now what can i use to create a keystore key? @Robert

Comment: If you don't have the keystore then you can't publish an update -> your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: yes but you sai me that javatool is not good anymore to create keystore keys, so how can i create a keystore keys NOW? @Robert

Comment: I was talking always about **signing**. `keystore` is usually the way for creating new a new keypair/keystore. Just make sure you generate an RSA key with at least 2048 bit.